# In wall splice for 4 wire cable

Tags: electrical, splicing, junction

I have used an in wall splice with Romex 14/2 that has 3 ports (hot, neutral, ground) but i would now like to use the same method to splice a 12/3 cable. I'm unable to find a splice with 4 ports. Can I just use two regular 3 port splices and divide it 2-2 or 3-1?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, but no need.

If you're referring to the Tyco Electronics Romex splice kits, yes, they make those for 3-wire w/ground as well as 2-wire w/ ground.

If you mean some other splice method, you have to read its instructions for whether it is suitable in-wall.  As far as I know the Tyco is the only one that is UL-listed for buried in-wall splicing.

Further, use of in-wall splice blocks is restricted.  It can only be done for repair, not extension for instance; and even then, only as a last resort when nothing else is possible.  If it is at all feasible for you to re-run the entire cable run, or a run to an accessible point (somewhere you want a receptacle, for instance), you must do that instead.

Comment: I'm using it for extension to avoid having a JB as per a suggestion in another recent question

Comment: It will go behind a wall and I'm not getting inspected. I could do a nut splice but my general strategy is to minimize the illegal work and nut splice behind a wall would be more illegal than an in wall splice

Comment: @amphibient I would either add that important detail to your question or ask a new question, so you can hear from some of the experts other than myself.  My understanding is the product was initially given carte-blanche, but usage was limited because of problems.  Best bet, find a place you want a receptacle. You can never have too many receptacles!

Comment: The area where this is all happening is a kitchen sink and I'm reducing chaos by eliminating JBs

Comment: If it is above the counter, extra receptacles are always handy. If it is below the counter, what's the big deal about having another junction box?

Comment: @amphibient Reduce chaos by eliminating code violations :)  You'll thank yourself when you put the house up for sale, because  you'll have fewer eyebrow-raisers to put on the disclosure sheet!

Comment: Home inspector won't be tearing walls to see what's behind

Comment: When I did my first demolition after buying the house, I found much worse things after tearing old drywall. Like in wall splicing that didn't even have nuts but only electrical tape.

Comment: @amphibient Just seems silly to go 90% of the way to complying with Code and not go the last 10%.  All the expense, none of the reward. But let's get a second opinion on the legality of those splices in your usage.  I've been wrong before.

Comment: I can't go 100%, can't replace the cable cause there's drywall and don't want JBs. The reward is unaffected as it's behind the wall and no inspection, (I hope)

Comment: NSi, BTW, makes a second-source equivalent to the Tyco NM splice kits, although it's kinda hard to find on their site

Comment: @amphibient is the problem the *quantity* of JBs in that location, or there mere *presence*? It seems silly to object to JBs tucked away inside a cabinet, anyway....

Answer (score 1):

No, all the conductors need to be part of the same assembly. A 4-hole version is NSi Model # [NMS-3](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/1e/1efc5e1c-a014-4054-8da8-ccdde2c19c82.pdf), they are about $15 from Home Depot.